# React components, is it better to use functions instead inline block event handlers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react, don't know how `render()` works internally. Which one is more efficient and the best practice for event handling in react components?

```
onNameChange (event) {
  this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}

render() {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={ this.state.name }
      onChange={ this.onNameChange.bind(this) }
    />
  );
}
```

OR

```
render() {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={ this.state.name }
      onChange={ (event) => this.setState({ name: event.target.value }) }
    />
  );
}
```

And what the case would be if we'd want to do something more than just setting the state with name? e.g. let's say we'd want to split `first` and `last` names then set the state:

```
render() {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={ `${ this.state.name.first } ${ this.state.name.last }` }
      onChange={ (event) => {
        let parts = event.target.value.split(' ');
        this.setState({ name: { first: parts[0], last: parts[1] }}); 
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference whether you create a new function by calling `.bind()` or by using an arrow function expression.

Comment: For your 2nd example, a bind call in the render path creates a brand new function on every single render.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way to avoid re-declaring the handler on every render?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling setState in render is not avoidable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290245/calling-setstate-in-render-is-not-avoidable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to bind the event handler in the constructor instead of binding or using a new arrow function in every render, at least from a perf perspective

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
}

onNameChange (event) {
 this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}

render() {
 return (
   <TextField
    value={ this.state.name }
    onChange={ this.onNameChange }
   />
 );
}
```