# how to update score dynamicaly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update my score by calling this.setState({player1: this.state.player1 + 1}).

But it does not allow me to do so. It says that i should do it outside the render method. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

The problem is on the render method in Board component, when i am checking the winner.

I am sorry if i am not precise. This is my first time trying to as a question.

```
    function Square(props) {
      return (
        <button className="square" onClick={() => props.onClick()}>
          {props.value}
        </button>
      );
    }

    class Board extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          squares: Array(9).fill(null),
          xIsNext: true,
          player1: 0,
          player2: 0
        };
      }

      handleClick(i) {
        const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
          return;
        }
        squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
        this.setState({ squares, xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext });
      }

      renderSquare(i) {
        return (
          <Square
            value={this.state.squares[i]}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        );
      }

      deleteBoard = () => {
        let squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        squares = Array(9).fill(null);
        this.setState({ squares, xIsNext: true });
      };

      render() {
        const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
        let status;
        if (winner) {
          status = "Winner: " + winner; 
//if(winner === 'X'){this.setState({player1: this.state.player1 + 1})}
        } else {
          status = "Next player: " + (this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => this.deleteBoard()}>Start over </button>{" "}
            </div>
            <div>Player1 {this.state.player1} </div>
            <div>Player2 {this.state.player2} </div>
            <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(0)}
              {this.renderSquare(1)}
              {this.renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(3)}
              {this.renderSquare(4)}
              {this.renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(6)}
              {this.renderSquare(7)}
              {this.renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    class Game extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
              <Board />
            </div>
            <div className="game-info">
              <div>{/* status */}</div>
              <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    // ========================================

    ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById("root"));

    function calculateWinner(squares) {
      const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
      ];

      for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
          return squares[a];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling setState in render is not avoidable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290245/calling-setstate-in-render-is-not-avoidable)

Comment: You can't call `setState()` in `render()`, because `setState()` triggers a re-render, so you'll go into an infinite loop. The logical choice it to check for a winner when they make a move, then handle it there. (`handleClick()` looks like the move handling function, though I only had a brief look over the code)

Comment: A good choice if you don't want to put it in the handleClick is to use componentDidUpdate() which can let you know when this.state.squares changes and you can call calculateWinner there

Answer (score 0):

You can't call setState in render since it triggers a re-render infinite loop.

Looks like you're already calculating the winner on every handleClick so you could setState in the calculateWinner function.