# React - How to set onChange to change the props directly?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have the following code that receives a variable and shows on the screen:

```
<input type="number" value={this.state.cpf} onChange={this.handleChange} name="name" />

handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({cpf: event.target.value});
      }

handleSignIn(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.cpf);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
```

I want to remove the handleChange, to change the direct props in onChange, I tried this but it did not work:

```
onChange={this.setState({ cpf: target.value })}
```

how do I change the onChange value with this.setState?

Comment: onChange takes a *function*

Comment: `onChange={event => this.setState({ cpf: event.target.value })}` should do the trick.

Comment: Your render method should always remain pure. Setting state in the render method t's a very bad practice and is more likely to have side effects

Comment: @lomse I try not to use the onChange method, but I can not type in form, do you know what happens? I want to change the value of the props without having to call a function, because I will use the updated value to make a post in an API.

Comment: Does your form input have a `value` property like this `<input value={this.state.inputValue}>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` here requires a function to be passed where it can inject the event as an argument. In your `onChange`, `target.value` will be undefined as there is not reference for value `target`.

Changing it to following should fix the issue.

```
onChange={(e) => {this.setState({ cpf: e.target.value})}
```

In this case the `onChange` event will have a function where it can pass the `event` object as `e` and you can perform your functionality.

Comment: Setting state in the render method isn't a good practice since the render method is supposed to be pure

Comment: @lomse the state is being set on the execution of the event. Its the similar to assign a handler to the onChange event.

Comment: Still a bad practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290245/calling-setstate-in-render-is-not-avoidable

Comment: Can you provide an better option for form manipulation here rather than just saying its a bad practice ? The example you have given is very specific to async call or functionalities that have side effects. As far as form manipulation is concern I would say we are fine with using setState here.

Answer (score 0):

Like @extempl pointed out, the handleChange event is not called because it's not binded to `this` so you either have to bind it by using.

There are several ways to solve this, depending on your code conventions, you could just bind the `this` keyword to the function like such:

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

or you could execute the function whenever onChange is triggered:

```
onChange={event () => this.handleChange(event)} // here i use the ES6 arrow function syntax.
```

NOTE: these are just examples, you could integrate this soulution into your own project

There are several other ways to do it as well, but these are some of the most common, I have provided a link to an article that explains, other methods as well:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ES6 arrows functions :

```
onChange={(event) => {
               this.setState({cpf: event.target.value});
          }
}
```

It work fine... GOOD Luck !