# ReactJS: Update nested state object properties without replacing whole object using setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to apply best practices when changing multiple property values of a nested object in my component's state.

My component code currently looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    object: {
      a: 10,
      b: 7,
      c: 12,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.setState({ object: { a: 5 }})}>change value a </button>
        <button onClick={this.setState({ object: { b: 2 }})}>change value b </button>
        <button onClick={this.setState({ object: { c: 3 }})}>change value c </button>
      </div>
      <p>{this.state.object.a}</p>
      <p>{this.state.object.b}</p>
      <p>{this.state.object.c}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

Before any button is clicked, you see three buttons followed by paragraphs reading `10`, `7` and `12` on the page.

Once I click the first button labeled "change value a", value `b` and `c` are  destroyed in my components state object which causes only the value of `5` to show. If I click the second button, then only `2` will show and prop `a` and `c` are gone.

I understand the behaviour, however I would like to know the best way to solve it. I want to keep it so all the values showing, and be able to update them in any order while the other values remain.

I am also pretty sure I am mutating the state directly and I know this is bad practice. I just don't know the right practice in this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling setState in render is not avoidable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290245/calling-setstate-in-render-is-not-avoidable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to address what you said, ***"I am mutating the state directly"***.

You are are not mutating state directly since you are calling `this.setState()`.

Since you want to update a specific part of `object: {}`, you can use the spread syntax or `Object.assign()` as follows:

```
this.setState({ object: { ...this.state.object, a: 5 } })
```

or

```
this.setState({ object: Object.assign({}, this.state.object, { a: 5 }) })
```

Because you called `this.setState()` in `render`, you will get the `Maximum call stack exceeded error`.

I can think of four ways to solve this, I'll show two of those.

1. Extract your call into a class method, then pass the reference to
   the click event handler.
2. Change this `onClick={this.setState({
       object: { c: 3 }})}` to `onClick={() => this.setState({ object: { c:
       3 }})}`

Comment: Using the spread operator work! Thank you! I actually had to full the function out of render though; it was giving me "Maximum update depth exceeded" error

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be by using the spread `...` operator on the nested `object` to merge the update of say `{ a: 5 }`, with the prior state of the `object` field:

```
// Create a new state object, with updated value of "5" for nested field "object.a"
{ object: { ...state.object, a: 5 }}
```

There are a few ways to incorporate this with `setState()` - one simple way is via a callback passed to `setState()`:

```
this.setState(state => { object: { ...state.object, a: 5 }})
```

This allow you to merge the nested `object`s prior state, with the state changes such as `{ a : 5 }` on `object`, without completely replacing all the nested `object` value in your state.

In the case of your render function, you could update the rendered result like so:

```
 render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={ () => this.setState(state => { object: { ...state.object, a: 5 }})}>change value a </button>
    <button onClick={ () => this.setState(state => { object: { ...state.object, b: 2 }})}>change value b </button>
    <button onClick={ () => this.setState(state => { object: { ...state.object, c: 5 }})}>change value c </button>
  </div>
  <p>{this.state.object.a}</p>
  <p>{this.state.object.b}</p>
  <p>{this.state.object.c}</p>
  );
  }
```

Comment: Using the spread operator work! Thank you! I actually had to full the function out of render though; it was giving me "Maximum update depth exceeded" error.

Comment: @EricChristensen great to hear :)