# Why does setState cause my React app go into infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render the following component, which is supposed to take the value of a few account level values and render the subtotal in a div. This is the code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ILiquidiManagerProps } from './ILiquidiManagerProps';
import {AccountValue} from './AccountFields';
import {LiquidTEUR} from './DummyContent';

interface SubtotalState {
    Account?: any,
    SubtotalValue?: any
  }

export default class SubtotalValues extends React.Component<ILiquidiManagerProps, SubtotalState> {
    public constructor(props: ILiquidiManagerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Account: LiquidTEUR.Subcategories.find(item => item.Name == this.props.label),
            SubtotalValue: 0
        }
    }
    
    private getText = data => {
        this.setState({SubtotalValue: data});
    }

    private initiateValue = () => {
        let Account = this.state.Account;
        let subtotal = 0;
        Account.Accounts.map((item) => {
            subtotal += item.Value;
        })
        this.setState({SubtotalValue: subtotal});
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<ILiquidiManagerProps> {
        this.initiateValue();
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
            <a className="collapsible" href="#">
                <div 
                    className={`p-2 text-right value ` + this.props.bgColor + ` font-weight-bold ` + this.props.textColor}
                    data-date={this.props.date}
                    data-name={this.props.label}
                >{this.state.SubtotalValue}</div></a>
            <div className="content hidden">
                {this.state.Account.Accounts.map((item, key) => {
                    return <AccountValue key={key} label={item.Value} getValue={this.getText} subtotal={this.state.SubtotalValue} />;
                })}
                <span className="add-pos">&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the error message it generates

> Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I have tried several different ways of setting the state of the subtotal, but I always seem to be getting the same error, and I am not sure where I am causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You call `this.initiateValue` when the component renders.
2. `initiateValue` sets the state
3. Setting the state triggers a render
4. GOTO 1

You *probably* want to call `initiateValue` from [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) instead.

(Or switch to writing a function component and putting it inside a `useEffect` hook).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `setState()` inside render method as you are using `this.initiateValue();`

Because as you know whenever `setState()` is called re-rendering happens that's the reason it's going for infinite.

> If you want to initialize data call inside `componentDidMount()` or `useEffect()`

For more understanding, you can refer to [Calling setState() in React from render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290245/calling-setstate-in-render-is-not-avoidable)